# how do I upgrade my elasticsearch in local

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch version is 2.4 
now I want the [latest version](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch) of elasticsearch.
any one who elaborate me step by step updating elasticsearch.
I am not worry about data or index.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using brew:

```
brew services stop elasticsearch
brew upgrade elasticsearch
brew services start elasticsearch
```